# Access SQL: using MIN() function with subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to calculate the 90th percentile on a column of my data. MS Access doesn't have a PERCENTILE function, so I'm taking the top 100 values (of 1000 in total), and then taking the minimum of the values that are returned. I'm however having some difficulty using the MS Access MIN() function. My query currently looks as follows:

```
SELECT MIN(*) 
FROM (SELECT TOP 100 ([table1].[field1] + [table1].[field2]) FROM [table1]);
```

This gives me the error:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'MIN(*'.
```

Why am I not allowed to use the asterisk with the MIN function? Am I calculating this value completely incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need an `order by` if you want to get the 90th percentile.

Second, you need a column name:

```
SELECT MIN(val) 
FROM (SELECT TOP 90 PERCENT ([table1].[field1] + [table1].[field2]) as val
      FROM [table1]
      ORDER BY ([table1].[field1] + [table1].[field2]) ASC
     ) as t;
```